# multicore x86 read or write of misaligned data

Tags: multithreading

On an x86, suppose I have a misaligned data item that spans a cache line boundary, say addresses 0x1fff through 0x2003 containing the little-endian 32-bit value 0x11223344. If thread A on core A does a write of 0x55667788 to that address, and thread B on core B "simultaneously" does a read of the same address, can that thread B potentially read a mix of the old and new value?

In other words, since A's misaligned write is going to be broken up by the processor into a one-byte write of 0x88 to address 0x1fff and a three-byte write of 0x556677 to address 0x2000, is it possible that B's read might happen in the middle of that misaligned write, and wind up reading 0x11223388 (or, if the write is split up in the reverse order, 0x55667711)?  Obviously the desirable behavior is for the read to return either the old value or the new one, and I don't care which, but not a mixture.

Ideally I'm looking for not just an answer to the question, but an authoritative citation of specific supporting statements in the Intel or AMD architecture manuals.

I'm writing a simulator for a multiprocessor system which had an exotic processor architecture, and in that system there are strong guarantees of memory access atomicity even for misaligned data, so the scenario I describe can't happen.  If I simulate each CPU as a separate thread on the x86, I need to ensure that it can't happen on the x86 either.  The information I've read about memory access ordering guarantees on the x86 doesn't explicitly cover misaligned cases.

Answer (score 0):

I posed the question because my attempt at testing it myself didn't turn up any instances in which the mixed read occurred.  However, that turns out to be due to a bug in my test program, and once I fixed that, it happens all the time on an AMD FX-8350.  On the other hand, if the misaligned data does not cross a cache line boundary, the problem does not seem to occur.

It appears that guaranteeing atomicity of misaligned reads and writes in my simulator will require either explicit locking or transactional memory (e.g., Intel's RTM).

My test program source code in C using pthreads is at:

https://gist.github.com/brouhaha/62f2178d12ec04a81078